# structure of arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, structure

I want ot assign hashtable to structure of array please help below is code

```
    public void SendCmdWithData(int IntCode, Hashtable Htbl) 
    {
        DatawithCommandCode[] arrData = new DatawithCommandCode[Htbl.Count];

        try {
            for (int intVal = 0; intVal < Htbl.Count - 1; intVal++) {
            }
        }
        catch (Exception) {}
    }
```

My Structure

```
    public struct DatawithCommandCode
    {
        public int CmdCode;
        public int Value;
    }
```

Comment: Did you try to assign it yourself? what errors OR exceptions you got?

Comment: @Azodious : I have no idea as Hashtable is Key Value and structure is of struct type,

Comment: If at all possible, avoid using `Hashtable` and instead use the generic `Dictionary`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it like following:

```
 public static void SendCmdWithData(int IntCode, Hashtable Htbl)
        {
            DatawithCommandCode[] arrData = new DatawithCommandCode[Htbl.Count];
            try
            {
                int i = 0;
                foreach (System.Collections.DictionaryEntry element in Htbl)
                {
                    DatawithCommandCode tempData = new DatawithCommandCode();
                    tempData.CmdCode = Convert.ToInt32(element.Key);
                    tempData.Value = Convert.ToInt32(element.Value);
                    arrData[i++] = tempData;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception) { }
        }
```

But I hope you are using .Net framework 2.0 or higher then its better to Use [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx)